# como buscar mediante un array de id's documentos en firebase

Tags: array, firebase

estoy tratando de traer ciertos documentos con ciertos id's y necesito traer solamente esos documentos, tengo lo siguiente

```
const pedidos = ["1","2",3","4"]
db.collection("pedidos").doc(pedido).get()
  .then(res => {
    console.log(res)
  })
```

busco realizar calgo como esto podrian ayudarme? gracias

Answer (score 0):

usando [FieldPath.documentId()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.FieldPath#static-documentid) puedes tratar el id como un campo más del documento. En tu caso necesitas una condición `where` con el operador `in`:

```
const pedidos = ["1", "2", "3", "4"]
db.collection("pedidos")
    .where(firebase.firestore.FieldPath.documentId(), "in", pedidos)
    .get()
    .then(res => {
        console.log(res)
    })
```